# Nested divs Background-color

Tags: css, html

I am trying to change background-color of the parent div behind the children ones. Kind of like how the how the background in [this image](http://thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/12/google_news_mobile_web_app.png) is darker than the other divs.
here is my HTML:

```
<div class="main"> 
    <div class="sub">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.main {
    background-color:#AAAAAA;
}

div.sub {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#AAAAAA;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #AAAAAA;
}
```

The main div is not the color #AAAAAA

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add background-color in sub class and also add padding for the clear view.

```
div.main {
background-color:#AAAAAA;
padding:20px;
}

div.sub {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#AAAAAA;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #AAAAAA;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

I tried doing the same thing, it may help: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osamayawar/NcZ2C/)

Comment: this is nearly literally the exact same thing i posted

Comment: @Jason and owner. kind of an unrelated question now, but when I add     background:url('images/noise.png'); into my CSS for one of the divs, nothing shows up: http://pastebin.com/DGtzv299

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do this now: http://jsfiddle.net/NcZ2C/2/  but as you can see the image does not show.

Comment: @breadedturtle please mark one of the answers as correct and create a new question if your original question has been answered

Answer (score 0):

just assign a different background color to your different divs, maybe add some padding to make it show?

```
div.main {
    background-color:#888888; //<---------- darker
    padding: 10px;            //<-------- padding
}

div.sub {
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#AAAAAA; //<---------- lighter
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#AAAAAA;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #AAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I made the .main div #AAAAAA and the .sub div #FFFFFF, but the whole thing is all grey: http://i.imgur.com/PkWt9ZY.jpg